# How to check which button is clicked but from blade template not from controller in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I want to know which button is clicked in the view not in the controller.
I have two buttons like this:

```
<button value="Show" name="Show">Show</button>
<button  value="update" name="update">Update</button>
@if(I click button "show" I want to see the following tags)
     <h2>title1</h2>
     <label>title 2 </label>
@elseif(I click the second button "update" I want to see the following tag)
      <span>title 3 </span><br>
@endif
```

Comment: Clicking a button will happen on the browser and that is **after** the view is rendered and sent. The only way you can react to a button click that happens at that point is with something that runs on the browser like JavaScript code. Since you've not tagged this question with any browser technologies I'm assuming you want a fully PHP/Laravel approach to this?

Comment: if(document.getElementById('button').clicked == true)
{
   alert("button was clicked");
}                                                                                              this method is useful in controller but not in view i want to find something like this.

Comment: Contents which you are going to show are static or dynamic?

Comment: dynamic Contents

Comment: you can use ajax or simply show hide the content container if the contents are already loaded. if show clicked, show the first container and hide other ..vice versa

Comment: The code you are writing there is JavaScript code which can't run in the Laravel controller at all.

Comment: So, there is no way in laravel (in blade) to get the name or the id of clicked button?